# Isometric Isomorphism between Banach Spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $K$ be a compact subspace of $X$. I am required to show that $C(X)/\{f:f|_K=0\}$ is isometrically isomorphism to $C(K)$. The norm used here the usual sup-norm.

I have shown that the quotient map induced by $\phi:f\mapsto f|_K$ is a surjective continuous map. The surjection follows from Tietze Extension Theorem. I am not sure how to proceed with the isometry part, although I have a feeling I have to use Urysohn's lemma somewhere.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Try remembering how is usually defined the norm on quotients

Comment: Which of the two inequalities have you tried to show? How far did you get? Have you shown injectivity yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**s:

Let $Z_K:=\{f:f|_K=0\}$
and $\alpha:C(X)/Z_K\to C(K)$, $f+Z_K\mapsto f|_K$ be the map of the question.

For showing the isometry part, let $f\in C(X)$ be given.
We have to show that $\|f+Z_K\|=\|f_K\|$ holds.

First, show the inequality $\|f+Z_K\|\geq \|f|_K\|$
using the definition of the norms.
For the other inequality, first find a function $g\in C(X)$
such that $g=f$ on $K$ but $\|g\|\leq \|f|_K\|$
(how can you construct such a function $g$?).
Then the other inequality follows because of $f+Z_K=g+Z_K$.